# Where do I change the block time parameters when compiling a NXT blockchain fork code?

Tags: blockchain

I'm using the NXT software to create my own blockchain, but I want to change the block time to 10 seconds vs default of 60 seconds. https://www.jelurida.com/nxt/blockchain-creation-kit Where do I change this parameter?

Answer (score -2):

You can change the block time on the following file:

https://bitbucket.org/Jelurida/ardor/src/b9bd3731bf6ad25b762d5f898e4c47c9dff4be48/src/java/nxt/Constants.java#lines-84

Under block_time in Ardor, but in NXT it is min_blocktime_limit.